# Amazon SWF: at least one worker has to be running, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I've just started out using the AWS Ruby SDK to manage as simple workflow. One behavior I noticed right away is that at least one relevant worker and one relevant decider must be running prior to submitting a new workflow execution.

If I submit a new workflow execution before starting my worker and decider, then the tasks are never picked up, even when I'm still well within time-out limits. Why is this? Based on the description of how the HTTP long polling works, I would expect either app to receive the relevant tasks when the call to poll() is reached.

I encounter other deadlocking situations after a job fails (e.g. due to a worker or decider bug, or due to being terminated). Sometimes, re-running or even just starting an entirely new workflow execution will result in a deadlocked workflow execution. The initial decision tasks are shown in the workflow execution history in the AWS console, but the decider never receives them. Admittedly, I'm having trouble confirming/reducing this issue to a test case, but I suspect it is related to the above issue. This happens roughly 10 to 20% of the time; the rest of the time, everything works.

Some other things to mention: I'm using a single task list for two separate activity tasks that run in sequence. Both the worker and the decider are polling the same task list.

Here is my worker:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'aws'
 
config_file_path = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'config.yaml')
config = YAML::load_file(config_file_path)
 
swf = AWS::SimpleWorkflow.new(config)
 
domain = swf.domains['test-domain']
 
puts("waiting for an activity")
domain.activity_tasks.poll('hello-tasklist') do |activity_task|
 
  puts activity_task.activity_type.name
  activity_task.complete! :result => name
 
  puts("waiting for an activity")
end
```

**EDIT**

Another user on the AWS forums commented:

> I think the cause is in SWF not immediately recognizing a long poll connection shutdown. When you kill a worker its connection for some time can be considered open by the service. So it still can dispatch a task to it. To you it looks like the new worker never getting it. The way to verify it is to check the workflow history. You'll see activity task started event with identify field that contains host and pid of the dead worker. Eventually such task is going to time out and can be retried by the decider.
>
> Note that such condition is common during unit tests that frequently terminate connections and is not really a problem for any production applications. The common workaround is to use different task list for each unit test.

This seems to be a pretty reasonable explanation. I'm going to try to confirm this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've raised two issues: one regarding start of an execution with no active deciders and the other regarding actors crashing in the middle of a task. Let me address them in order.

I have carried out an experiment based on your observations and indeed, when a new workflow execution starts and no deciders are polling SWF still thinks that a new decision task gets started. The following is my event log from the AWS console. Note what happens:

```
Fri Feb 22 22:15:38 GMT+000 2013 1 WorkflowExecutionStarted
Fri Feb 22 22:15:38 GMT+000 2013 2 DecisionTaskScheduled
Fri Feb 22 22:15:38 GMT+000 2013 3 DecisionTaskStarted
Fri Feb 22 22:20:39 GMT+000 2013 4 DecisionTaskTimedOut
Fri Feb 22 22:20:39 GMT+000 2013 5 DecisionTaskScheduled
Fri Feb 22 22:22:26 GMT+000 2013 6 DecisionTaskStarted
Fri Feb 22 22:22:27 GMT+000 2013 7 DecisionTaskCompleted
Fri Feb 22 22:22:27 GMT+000 2013 8 ActivityTaskScheduled
Fri Feb 22 22:22:29 GMT+000 2013 9 ActivityTaskStarted
Fri Feb 22 22:22:30 GMT+000 2013 10 ActivityTaskCompleted
...
```

The first decision task was immediately scheduled (which is expected) and started right away (i.e. allegedly dispatched to a decider, even though no decider was running). I started a decider in the meantime, but the workflow didn't move until the timeout of the original decision task, 5 minutes later. I can't think of a scenario where this would be the desired behavior. Two possible defenses against that: have deciders running before starting a new execution or set an acceptably low timeout on a decision task (these tasks should be immediate anyway).

The issue of crashing actor (either decider or worker) is one that I'm familiar with. A short background note first:

Both activity and decision tasks are recored by the service in 3 stages:

- Scheduled = ready to be picked up by an actor.
- Started = already picked up by an actor.
- Completed/Failed or Timed out = the actor either or completed failed or not finished the task within deadline.

Once the actor picked up a task and crashed, it is obviously not going to report anything back to the service (**unless** it is able to recover and still remembers *task token* of the dispatched task - but most crashing actors wouldn't be that smart). The next time a decision task will be scheduled, will be upon time-out of the recently dispatched task, which is why all actors seem to be blocked for the duration of a task timeout. This is actually the desired behavior: The service can't know whether the task is being worked on or not as long as the worker still works within its deadline. There is a simple way to deal with this: fit your actors with a try-catch block and fail a task when an unexpected crash happens. I would discourage from using separate tasklists for each integ test. Instead, I'd recommend failing the task in the `teardown()` block.  SWF allows to specify a `reason` for failing a task, which is one way of logging failures and viewing them later through the AWS console.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I figured I was doing something wrong the whole time, but it looks like everything is more or less working as expected. I hadn't gotten to writing a test myself.

Comment: Pleasure is mine, I had a blast doing it and ended up learning something.